# How to create notification groups OneSignal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification, onesignal

In my app I've got buttons where if the user presses it they are then 'subscribed' to that channel and will receive notifications for that and which ever other ones they subscribe to. I wanted to know how to do this with OneSignal you can create user segments and send notifications to only those specific groups. So if I create a segment in OneSignal how can I register users to that segment and remove them?

Xcode, swift 3, iOS 10

Answer (score 1):

Use Tags. (from [FrontEnd](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/cordova-sdk#section--sendtags-) or [API](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#edit-device))

**Example using Frontend:**

- window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTags({key: "value", key2: "value2"});

**Example using API:**

- URL:

  - https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/PLAYER_ID
- METHOD:

  - PUT
- HEADERS:

  - ContentType: application/json
- BODY (json):

  {
    "app_id": "APP_ID",
    "tags": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
    }
  }